# use variable in chained method usage

Tags: php, oop, chained

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('myentity',$entity); 
$data[$key]['field_test'] = $wrapper ->field_test ->value();
```

the above code works fine but it doesn't work if i replace the chained property with a variable.

```
$field_name = 'myfield';
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('myentity',$entity); 
$data[$key][$field_name] = $wrapper ->$field_name ->value();
```

the error:'PHP Error: Function name must be a string'

How can i work around this? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
$data[$key][$field_name] = $wrapper->$field_name->value();
```

to

```
$data[$key][$field_name] = $wrapper->{$field_name}->value();
```

See:: [Curly Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Comment: Thank you! After reading your anwser, i tried again.surprisingly, this time it works, even without the curly brace.it must be something else that made it not working before. the problem is solved.

Comment: @benson if it solved your problem you cud mark it as Accepted answer.. .